# what is the codec for JSON facebook for information downloaded?

Tags: python, json, facebook, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have to deal with a JSON file I downloaded from facebook with all my info. 
The JSON itself I will manage but I have a problem BEFORE I start to work with the files.
I cannot determine the codec for the file downloaded. I tried on Win and Mac, using Python 3 under Jupyter Notebook. The code is the following:

```
f = open("testefc.json", "r", encoding="iso-8859-1")
f.read()
```

I tried utf-8, latin1 and several others but it seems none can translate properly.
My file has this text:

```
"Voc\u00c3\u00aa est\u00c3\u00a1 num processo de sele\u00c3\u00a7\u00c3\u00a3o"
```

and I know that it means `"você está num processo de seleção"`. I could try to replace every code but I figure there must be a easyier way.
Download using html does not suit my needs, unfortunatelly.

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you json decode it?

Comment: If this is JSON (it looks a lot like it), then use the `json` module, eg. `s = json.decode(f)` (without `f.read()`). JSON files should be encoded with one UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, so Latin-1 isn't usually a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to open the file with utf-8 encoding? Your approach mentions latin-1 and utf-8, thus I think you probably confused encodings and did not decode the json file correctly. Try

```
>>> f = open('testefc.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
>>> f.read()
'Você está num processo de seleção'
>>> f.close()
```

Note that this is equivalent to opening the file in binary mode (leaving the encoding unspecified) and afterwards decoding it manually

```py
>>> f = open('testefc.json', 'rb')
>>> f.read().decode('utf-8')
'Você está num processo de seleção'
>>> f.close()
```

It seems like you erroneously decoded the json file to latin-1, yet the original text encoding is utf-8 (compare with the facebook.com page source: `<meta charset="utf-8" />`). When you encode your example text to latin-1 again and decode it to utf-8, you obtain the properly decoded Python string.

```py
>>> l = 'Voc\u00c3\u00aa est\u00c3\u00a1 num processo de sele\u00c3\u00a7\u00c3\u00a3o'.encode('latin1')
>>> s = l.decode('utf-8')
>>> s
'Você está num processo de seleção'
```

Comment: Your first example doesn't look right. In Python 3, using `'rb'` with `encoding=` raises `ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument`. In Python 2, the `open()` function doesn't accept an `encoding=` parameter at all and raises `TypeError`. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: You are right, that was a mistake. It should be `'r'` instead of `'rb'` when specifying an encoding. `'rb'` would only work if we do not specify the encoding when opening the file, but decode the read bytes object like so: `f.read().decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: I tried enconding utf-8 but it did not work. somehow the code below did work beatfully:
l = 'Voc\u00c3\u00aa est\u00c3\u00a1 num processo de sele\u00c3\u00a7\u00c3\u00a3o'.encode('latin1')
s = l.decode('utf-8')
s
>> 'Você está num processo de seleção'
When I tried the code below, using the file as input, I got an error:
f = open('testefc.json', 'r')
f.read().decode('utf-8')
>> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
Wierd...

Comment: The AttributeError is telling you what's wrong: you can't decode a str, since it was already decoded implicitly when you opened it like this `f = open('testefc.json', 'r')`. Now you only have to do `f.read()` and you will receive a correct string representation in memory. Look carefully at the answer; `f.read().decode('utf-8')` only makes sense when you open the file as `'rb'`.